# Deep Linking iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, deep-linking

I am currently working on an iOS game that is live. http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/nomnom-combo/id498050261?mt=8

Currently, I am trying to implement deep linkig for our app.

We I post a story link, for example a wall post boasting about a high score, the deep linking works only for app developer iPhones. Sand box mode is disabled.

Is there a way to make the app live? To enable it?

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: What exactly do you mean by deep linking?

Comment: Did you try making deep linking enabled in Facebook app settings?

Comment: Thanks for your responses.

I've enabled iOS native deep linking in my app configuration.

What I mean by deep linking, is when a user is browsing Facebook, and someone post a link about my game, if they click my story link, it automatically redirects them to the game or to the app store if they don't have it installed.

Comment: Off the Facebook web reference: "When you have enabled iOS native deep linking in the Dev app, published stories on Facebook for iOS will link back to your app if they have it installed, or the Apple App Store if they do not. Facebook will apply re-writing rules to redirect these links back to your app. See here to see how you can implement deep linking so users go to the correct content in your app."

Please note that this actually works for my Facebook accounts signed up as Admins to this app. It doesn't work for anyone not associated with the App.

Cheers

Comment: Maybe your facebook app is in the sandbox?

Comment: I don't have a fix, but I'm debugging deep linking on my app right now. I'm doing a lot of alerts on the receiving, target devices, to determine where things are breaking. If you can do this, you might be able to figure out more what's going on. Such as: are the links have the right protocol? (fb_appid) on the wall, are the strings (target url) showing up right in the app? Or just not appearing at all, etc.